# Why crashes from Organizer in Project won't take me to the place it crashed?

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports, xcode-organizer

When I try to open a crash in project via crashes from Organizer it won't take me anymore to the line of code that crashed and neither give me details about this crash. Any idea why?

Note:Project is an old application.

Comment: Any other details? How do you recognize it as crash? Especially what happens when you launch app in debug mode?

Comment: go to XCode->Window->Organizer->tap on an app -> go to crash view and you see there a list of crashes from users -> tap on one -> tap Open in Project. It should take me at last line before crash and give me in log more details

Answer (score 3):

You say that the project is an old application. Does the source code version you have in Xcode match the version of the application that generated the crash report? If your source is newer than the application version that generated the crash, the information in the symbols for the crash dump will not match up and the links may not work.

Answer (score 0):

use AddExceptionBreakpoint from xcode **debug** -> **breakpoint** **createExceptionBreakpoint** This will help you .BTW what is the crash description shown in LogView

Comment: Hi there, Don't know what should do addException but it doesn't... and in the log view i have no crash description. Don't quite understand why?!

Comment: This answer is a comment and doesn't answer the question